# Gmaps4rails - individual infowindow for clusters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I would like to create an infowindow by using `gmaps4rails gem` and I also put clusters. So far, I can create clusters but when I click on clusters it zooms in, in to individual markers. I am using partial template to show the information. However, I could not do the template. Because I can not get individual info of the marker. So, it shows all the info of the markers. Here;

[image]

After zoom out;

[image]

What I like to have to do is, It shows clusters like the second page and when I click infowindow opens. Instead it zooms in like the first picture.

Here is my `locations_controller`;

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
    
  def index

    if params[:search].present? 
        @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 5) #Kac mile cevresinde aranıldıgının bilgisi bu km ile değişebilir
    else
        @locations = Location.all
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
        marker.lat location.latitude
        marker.lng location.longitude
        marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/locations/my_template", :formats => [:html], :locals => { :object => location}) 
      
    end
  end
  

end
```

here is `_my_template` partial;

```
<% @locations.each do |location|%>
<li>
<%= location.address %>
</li>

<% end %>
```

and the `index.html.erb`;

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <li><%=location.address %></li> (<%= location.distance.round(2) %> miles)

<% end %>
</ul>




<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", { markers: { maxRandomDistance: 5 , clusterer: {gridSize: 45, maxZoom: 20} } })
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

**EDIT 1:**

But here is an example of clusterer info window

[image]

or this is an pop up window?

Comment: you cant have an infowindow for a clusterer, its only for markers

Comment: fyi this is the library used: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html and it deosnt provide infowindows

Comment: Yes, but then how can I customize the template to show individual informations on markers. Now whatever marker I click, it shows all the information as you can see from the code

Comment: if you use gmaps4rails, it just takes he content of what you put in infowindow